# Xcode 12 - Storyboard screens showing up empty/black (using m1 macbook)

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode12

We have tried both iOS 14 and 13. In both cases, the storyboard screens show up like this.

Has anyone else faced this issue and was able to solve it? Or should we revert back to xcode 11 or 10 in order to solve this?

[Empty storyboard screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLvwB.jpg)

Comment: Since there is no programming specific problem, I would recommend posting at http://apple.stackexchange.com as you will likely see a better response

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Have the same issue but never see this post on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I tried opening the project on my **iMac 2017** (Intel) basically almost the same specs as my M1 Macbook, but do not have an issue with rendering the storyboard screens. I presume there might be anything I'm missing or something else since this would be my first time using an M1 Mac.

Comment: Linking to a question in their developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/674182?answerId=664856022#664856022

Answer (score 5):

I have similar issue with Xcode 12.4 on M1 Macbook Pro. As a workaround disable Rosetta Mode when working with storyboard. Follow the below steps

1. Quit Xcode and open finder and go to Applications folder
2. Right click on Xcode App and select Get Info
3. Uncheck "Open using Rosetta" option
4. Open Xcode, storyboard will work now

Note: With Rosetta Disabled, I wasn't able to build/run the app. So I was toggling the Rosetta mode. I think Apple will fix it sooner.

**UPDATE**

Xcode 12.5+ fixed this issue.

Comment: I m facing this issue in Xcode 14.3

Answer (score 0):

I tried on Xcode 12.5 beta on my M1 pro is work well. That's Xcode issue with 12.4 on M1.

Comment: how to get 12.5 beta ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/download/ 
install macos beta profile. 
then use can update it.

Answer (score 0):

Selected a device from the list in `Device` in Xcode fixed it for me:

Tap `Device`:

[image]

Then select a device:

[image]